# iOS Connect to Wi-Fi via EAP-TTLS and EAP-PEAP

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi

I will briefly explain to you what problem I'm having.

I spent a lot of time to find the solution but without any positive result.

So I hope that you can help me.

Our app is used to connect to a secure network via NEHotspotConfiguration.

NEHotspotConfiguration *configuration = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc] initWithSSID:networkName eapSettings:settings];

I configured NEHotspotEAPSettings with: username, password, outerIdentity, identity, supportedEAPTypes (NEHotspotConfigurationEAPTypeEAPTTLS and NEHotspotConfigurationEAPTypeEAPPEAP), trustedServerNames and trustedServerCertificates (client.cer and rootCA.cer).

Those certificates were generated by the guys from the server side and are incorporated in the iOS project via xcode.

I have checked if those certificates are valid. For example, in the debuger logs I can see the expiration date.

In the final step when the alert message appears that the app wants to join the secure network, after pressing the join button we see the message "Unable to join the network".

In the debuger logs I see the following:

NEHotspotEAPSettings failed to find persistent reference for identity. status = -25300

NEHotspotEAPSettings failed to find persistent reference for trusted server certificate. status = -25300

NEHotspotEAPSettings found nil persistent reference for identity

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it or what is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

This is the code for successful authentication

`NEHotspotEAPSettings *eapSettings = [[NEHotspotEAPSettings alloc] init]; eapSettings.username = @"username"; eapSettings.password = @"password"; eapSettings.supportedEAPTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NEHotspotConfigurationEAPTypeEAPPEAP], nil]; eapSettings.outerIdentity = @""; eapSettings.trustedServerNames = @[@"xxx.xxx.com"]; NEHotspotConfiguration *hotspotConfig = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc]initWithSSID:@"ssidName" eapSettings:eapSettings]; [[NEHotspotConfigurationManager sharedManager] applyConfiguration:hotspotConfig completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) { NSLog(@"success"); }];`

This is the code for authentication failure

`NSString *caCertificatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"caCertificate" ofType:@"cer"];
NSData *caCertificateData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:caCertificatePath];
SecCertificateRef caCertificateRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDataRef)caCertificateData);

```
SecCertificateRef userCertificate = nil;
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"userCertificate" ofType:@"cer"];
NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (__bridge CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;
CFStringRef password = CFSTR("password");
const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase }; };
const void *values[] = { password };
CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);
CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inPKCS12Data, options, &items);
CFRelease(options);
CFRelease(password);
if (securityError == errSecSuccess) {
NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate. Items: %ld", CFArrayGetCount(items));
CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    userCertificate = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict, kSecImportItemIdentity);
    NEHotspotEAPSettings *eapSettings = [[NEHotspotEAPSettings alloc] init];
    eapSettings.tlsClientCertificateRequired = YES;
    eapSettings.trustedServerNames = @[@"xxx",@"xxx.xxx.com"];
    eapSettings.supportedEAPTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NEHotspotConfigurationEAPTypeEAPTLS], nil];
    eapSettings.outerIdentity = @"xxxx";
    [eapSettings setTrustedServerCertificates:@[(__bridge id)caCertificateRef]];
    [eapSettings setIdentity: userCertificate];
    NEHotspotConfiguration *hotspotConfig = [[NEHotspotConfiguration alloc]initWithSSID:@"ssidName" eapSettings:eapSettings];
    [[NEHotspotConfigurationManager sharedManager] applyConfiguration:hotspotConfig completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"failure");//NEHotspotEAPSettings failed to find persistent reference for identity. status = -25300
    }];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error opening Certificate.");
}
```

`

The difference between the two is that I want to use certificate authentication not username password authentication

By the way, the test device is iphone12pm, the version is ios16.2, the controller is Cisco.

1、Check the Apple Developer website
2、No valid information in Google Bing and other website searches

Comment: It sounds like you have been provided with certificates that are not trusted by the iOS device

Comment: I made sure that the server root certificate and the personal certificate are both correct, both in cer format. I was able to connect through the system level installation, and it reported an error through the code.

Comment: The error code indicates "item not found" https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-25300 https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-25300 which correlates with the error text; a trusted root certificate cannot be found for the certificate you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance
1, that is, the root certificate on the phone must use the one stored in OSStatus and cannot use the one imported manually, right?
2. Another problem is that I can store the string in the code, but I can't store the certificate file, no error is reported in xcode. Here is my code